# Is it possible to write a custom Power Query Connector?

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Power Query under “From Other Sources”, we see a number of specialized providers (Facebook, SAP, SalesForce, etc).

I am interested in writing a custom provider to access a local proprietary data store that cannot be consumed via any of the built in connectors.

I am aware that "the recommended way" to access data stores that do not have a supporting connector is to expose & consume the data via an OData feed.  However, I would very much like to have a user friendly interface such that the user can easily find the specific feed they want.

From playing with some of the different providers, it seems like there are 2 parts:

a)  The UI for specifying mandatory connection parameters, and optionally choosing specific entities and filters
b)  The provider of the physical data itself (Facebook.Graph(), Sql.Database(), etc)

Is there currently a way to write a custom Connector, or are Connectors 100% proprietary and only provided by Microsoft?

EDIT:

I should note, knowledgeable "no it's not possible and here's why I think so" answers are definitely encouraged.  I'm mainly asking *is it possible*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but it's an area we're actively exploring. However, we do not foresee allowing a custom UI to be built for a custom connector.

Comment: Thanks Curt.  Wouldn't a custom UI be kind of mandatory though?

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered providing a proper & easy API to the model & connections that I could manipulate from an add-in?  I'd just like to have my more user friendly add-in to locate and *create* the connection, and then once it's there Power Query could treat it like any other SQL connection, that would be perfectly fine for me.  So, is there any possibility of this, or does MS plan to limit access to the model for strategic reasons?

Comment: That's not the kind of thing that would be likely be driven by strategic concerns.

Comment: Power Query is built into Excel 2016, and there is some ability to drive Power Query through the Excel Object Model. I'm not sure it's advanced enough yet to do what it sounds like you want, but it's probably worth investigating.

Comment: The exact same question from almost two years ago:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cadde94-dac8-4ab6-91d8-e58ab3cb26c8/custom-data-adapters-for-powerquery?forum=powerquery

Comment: So this idea isn't new or unique.  If we had access to the model API (which already exists, as Power Query uses it) then we'd be free to implement these very useful features on our own.  Which makes me curious: what might be the reasoning behind the decision to *not* expose a useful API that already exists?

Comment: I suggest the best way to achieve the result you want ("a user friendly interface such that the user can easily find the specific feed they want") is to build the Queries yourself (based on OData, web services or whatever), then publish them as certified queries to your organizations Power BI site (aka Data Catalog). That already has functionality for them to preview the data, take it and shape it for their own needs.

Comment: @MikeHoney Thanks, and agreed, that is currently the "recommended way" to do this sort of thing, but it is an inferior solution.  Using similar logic, one could argue that there is little point of developing Power Query itself, as you "could" accomplish most things in native Excel (but the Power Query implementation is *vastly* superior).

I think these are perfectly legitimate questions to put to the PQ team.  It would be a Good Thing if they were as transparent as other teams at Microsoft.  For example:  https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: @CurtHagenlocher I have developed custom data connector ".mez" in VS. Can we use it with Excel or Power Query in Excel. (Not Power BI)?

Comment: Any updates regarding the ability to use a custom data connector in Excel?

Comment: "Any updates?" As of January 2023, the Excel team has not shown any interest in supporting custom connectors.