# Excel Power Query custom data connector

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is it currently possible to build a custom data connector for **EXCEL** Power Query? If yes, where can i find more info?

I'm seeing all these custom connectors for Power BI, but NOT for **EXCEL** Power Query.

If it's not possible, I would really appreciate an official link where that's mentioned.

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is some Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/install-sdk).

Comment: thank you, but I don't find any reference there that custom data connectors are possible in Excel or not. the only thing i found so far is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485593/is-it-possible-to-write-a-custom-power-query-connector?rq=1

Comment: Microsoft hasn't really poured many resources into Power Query for Excel to my knowledge, which also explains performance for some queries. I think they are concentrating on Power BI. Theoretically, it's the same technology, but the documentation points strictly to Power BI.